# Send an HTTP request to SharePoint with GET Method and GetByTitle URI

Tags: power-automate

I am trying to build an approval flow in Power Automate following the walk-through https://kamdaryash.wordpress.com/2020/04/

My target folder on the SharePoint is located in a folder (Shared Documents/MyFolder)

one step 4 (Send an HTTP request to SharePoint), I have the following:

```
 - Site Address: approvals - https://something.sharepoint.com/sites/SOPapprovals
 - Method: GET
 - Uri: _api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle(‘Shared%20Documents/MyFolder’)/Items?$select=EncodedAbsUrl,FileLeafRef,ID&$Filter=Id eq ItemId
 - Header: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=nometadata"}
```

Only problem is that I am always getting the following error message

```
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<m:code>
-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException
</m:code>
<m:message xml:lang="en-US">
The expression "Web/Lists/GetByTitle(‘Shared Documents/0. Submitted For Approval’)/Items" is not valid.
</m:message>
</m:error>
```

Does anyone have an idea where the problem is coming from ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('SubmitForApproval')/Items